# Right Click JUnit wont show. People say that there is a Junit built in in java eclipse, there is one at the library junit 3.0

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Right Click -> New -> "NO JUNIT SHOWN"

[image]

Comment: click on other there you will be having Junit Test

Comment: Consider adding some text that explains just exactly what your problem is. A little effort can go a long way.

Comment: I think this is the Java EE perspective. is it the same with Java perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLick on "New -> Other..." then chose category Java->JUnit and then select JUnit Test

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do i put JUnit Test Case on the Menu everytime I rightclick?

Answer (score 0):

The list of so called "New menu shortcuts" depends on the active perspective. So please either switch to the Java perspective first to get that shortcut menu, or just use *File->New->Other*, where you will always get the complete selection of available wizards.